# What type of data can a Repository return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewmodel, repository-pattern

I have a website, build using ASP.NET MVC, that uses the repositories.

A Controller retrieves data using the repository like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = userRepository.GetAll();
```

When the View needs more complex data, the Controller returns a ViewModel like:

```
public class UserDataViewModel
{
    User User { get; set; }
    Otherdata data { get; set; }
}
```

My question is - Can the repository return a ViewModel? Like:

```
UserDataViewModel data = userRepository.GetComplexUserData(int userId);
```

Or, could you pass in the Viewmodel as a ref:

```
userRepository.SetComplexUserData(int userId, ref UserDataViewModel data);
```

Or should the repository be completely unaware of the ViewModels?
And should you then build a new class that is identical to the ViewModel and use that in the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at repository pattern's [definition](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) by Martin Fowler

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a
>   collection-like interface for accessing **domain objects**.

So this essentially means that threre is no place for ViewModels in repositories.

ViewModel is just a wrapper that make it easier for View to work with your domain objects. Model shouldn't know anything about the way its presented

Lets say, you have model:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

In this case your viewmodel will look like

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    readonly User _user;
    readonly User _model;

    public UserViewModel(User user, OtherData data)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public User User
    { 
        get { return _user; }
    }

    public OtherData Data
    { 
        get { return _data; }
    }    

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Id is requred")]
    public Guid Id 
    { 
        get { return _user.Id; }
        set { _user.Id = value; } 
    }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]  
    public string Name     
    { 
        get { return _user.Name; }
        set { _user.Name = value; } 
    } 

    // TODO: Add OtherData fields you want to expose to view
}
```

Get data from repository

```
var user = userRepository.GetById(id);
var data = userRepository.GetComplexUserData(id);
var vm = new UserViewModel(user, data);
```

Save data to repository (can also split to 2 statements and use UnitOfWork)

```
userRepositoty.SetComplexUserData(vm.User, vm.Data);
```

Comment: So to get the data, i have to do two trips to the database?

In my case, i have five database tables i need to return... perferebly in one DB call.

Comment: You should think about how OtherData is related to User. Maybe OtherData is a logical part of User and they should always come together? Anyway if you want to do it in one trip, you could use Tuple<User, OtherData> as result